# LaTeX editor with GUI for Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: texlive, ubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides)

I've installed TeXLive but I found it complicated. Actually I couldn't run it completely. So I need a LaTeX editor with GUI on Ubuntu 12.10. What's your suggestions?

*Note:* I'm new to LaTeX and I'm trying to learn.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You should have a look at [this discussion](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides).

Comment: @Corentin I love how you handled this situation; many people (especially experienced users with high rep such as yourself) brusquely comment something to the effect of "Oh, you're one of those careless buffoons who don't take the time to check for dupes; look at this, and search first next time, instead of wasting everyone else's time" without considering that sometimes the asker can be partially informed (rather than partially human). Your respect for others and sensitivity for the beginner's situation has been noted. Welcoming is _always_ better than spurning in my opinion; keep it up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using TeXworks with Ubuntu 12.10. It is easy to use. You could also try Gummi. They are both in the Ubuntu Software Center.

Answer (score 0):

Texmaker works great for me! See: [Home page](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/), [Ubuntu package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/tex/texmaker)

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to LaTeX, you may want to try LyX, http://www.lyx.org/, which is pretty easy to use and provide a good user interface if you are not used to LaTeX.

It is a WYSIWYM, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYM. I write in LaTeX on a daily basis and use this software which incredibly simplify my life. I never switched back to TeXLive or other.